# foreign key of database management System

Tags: mysql

what is composite foreign Key?

Comment: Please make some effort before posting questions as simple as these, try and Google, read a few articles and post a particular aspect of the problem. You are wasting everyone's time and abusing a system like this by asking such questions!

Answer (score 2):

If you are referencing a table that has a composite primary key (on composed from more than one column), the foreign key must also have the same columns, hence, a composite foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

'Composite' refers to composing a key out of "multiple" keys. Take this example where table A has composite primary key using two columns (A1, A2). Hence, another table referring to this table will also have a composite foreign key .. in this case (B2, B3).

```
TABLE A( A1, A2, A3,
  PRIMARY KEY(A1, A2)
)

TABLE B( B1, B2, B3, B4,
  FOREIGN KEY(B2, B3) REFERENCES A(A1, A2)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are compound and composite keys.

**Compound** keys are keys made out of 2 or more columns.
Each of the attributes that make up the compound key are **simple keys**.

Most of the keys we work with are actually compound keys, not composite keys.

**Composite** key is a key made out of 2 or more attributes, but each of those attributes is NOT a simple key. Example would be creating a key out of first name and e-mail address - neither are simple keys.

This is nitpicking, and for most purposes we can refer to keys as composite. However, the difference does exist and I thought it should be mentioned.

Composite foreign key would be a key pointing to a record whose referenced keys are not simple keys.